# Batch writing to database through cx_Oracle progressively slows over time

Tags: python-3.x, database, oracle12c, cx-oracle

I'm writing a large number of rows (~300 million) to a database table through the cx_Oracle library within Python 3.6. The inputs are read for a number of scenarios, with each scenario generating millions of rows to be written to the database table. The rows are being written in batches of ~500,000 rows at a time using the WriteToDatabase function below. I found larger batches provided greater performance than smaller batches. Note the table is truncated prior to this process. For reference, this is what the writing speed per batch looks like: [Output time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8GJV.png)

I thought the issue may be due to storing unnecessary variables in memory which are being cleared when func2 returns. So I manually deleted the unnecessary variables and called the garbage collector (gc.collect). While this provided an improvement in performance, the underlying problem of decreased performance over time remains.

```
def func1(args1):  
    for xx in range(0,NumberofScenarios):  
        def func2(args2,xx):  
            #Perform analysis using xx  
            def func3(args3):  
                del unnecessary_variables   
                gc.collect()  
                WriteToDatabase(curs, ListofTuples):  
            func3(args3)  
        func2(args2,xx) 



def WriteToDatabase(curs, ListofTuples):       
    curs.executemany("""  
        insert /*+ APPEND_VALUES NOLOGGING*/ into table1  
        (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)  
        values (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5)  
    """, ListofTuples  
    )
```

I do not understand why returning from and calling the function (func2) would impact the performance of writing to the database.

Any ideas on what is causing the issue and how to address it?

Comment: Fix your code snippet with backticks ` or tildes ~ to properly emphasize it.

Comment: What's slow?  Creating ListofTuples?  The DB itself (try AWR and other DB tools)?  The network?  This question is probably best asked at the cx_Oracle GitHub repo.